# NLP : Error/Unknown/misspelled text Detection model of a patient's medical text file

Tags: nlp, data-science, text-mining, medical

I have few patient's medical record text files which i got from the internet and i want to identify/find the files which are bad quality(misspelled words/special characters between the words/Erroneous words) and files with good quality(clean text).i want to build error detection model using text mining/NLP.

1)can someone please help me on the approach and solution for feature extraction and model selection.
2)Is there any medical corpus for medical records to identify the misspelled/Erroneous words.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to simply correct these misspelled words to improve performance on whatever downstream task you want to do, then I can suggest a simple approach which has worked sufficiently well for me.

1. First tokenize your text (I recommend `scispacy` for medical text)
2. Identify possible "bad quality" words simply by the count of each unique word constructed from all the words in your corpus e.g. all words that occur <= 3 times
3. Add words that occur > 3 times in your corpus (we assume these are all correctly spelled) to a regular English dictionary. If your corpus is large, this is perfectly adequate for capturing medical terms. Otherwise use a medical dictionary e.g. UMLS, or https://github.com/glutanimate/wordlist-medicalterms-en to add the medical words not in a regular dictionary
4. Use `pyspellchecker` to identify the misspellings by using the Levenshtein Distance algorithm and comparing against our dictionary.
5. Replace the typos with what `pyspellchecker` thinks they should be.

A basic example:

```
import spacy
import scispacy
from collections import Counter
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_sci_md') # sciSpaCy
word_freq = Counter()

for doc in corpus:
    tokens = nlp.tokenizer(doc)
    tokenised_text = ""

    for token in tokens:
        tokenised_text = tokenised_text + token.text + " "

    word_freq.update(tokenised_text.split())

infreq_words = [word for word in word_freq.keys() if word_freq[word] <= 3 and word[0].isdigit() == False]
freq_words = [word for word in word_freq.keys() if word_freq[word] > 3]
add_to_dictionary = " ".join(freq_words)
f=open("medical_dict.txt", "w+")
f.write(add_to_dictionary)
f.close()

spell = SpellChecker()
spell.distance = 1  # set the distance parameter to just 1 edit away - much quicker
spell.word_frequency.load_text_file('medical_dict.txt')

misspelled = spell.unknown(infreq_words)
misspell_dict = {}
for i, word in enumerate(misspelled):
    if (word != spell.correction(word)):
        misspell_dict[word] = spell.correction(word)

print(list(misspell_dict.items())[:10])
```

I would also recommend using regular expressions to fix any other "bad quality" words which can be systematically corrected.

Comment: Thank you amin for the response:) i have few questions  ,before i present the questions my goal is actually to built a strong error detection model that can identify whether a page of the patient’s medical chart is of bad quality(erroenous terms,mis-spelled words,special chars like AAAAA,btfhj${>*£..etc rather than spell correction model

Comment: My question is ,i believe we cannot identify bad quality words simply by having the assumption of  all word counts less than 3 (eg:stamach is mispelled which should be stomach ) instead is there any possibility to derive features and build a model like svm,random forest...etc to classify or predict whether the page is good with clean words or bad with mispelled ,spl.chars words...etc

Comment: No worries Mukesh, do your documents have labels saying which ones are bad quality or not? If they do, try BioBERT like Akshat suggests. Otherwise, you need to try an unsupervised approach. E.g. something like https://towardsdatascience.com/applying-machine-learning-to-classify-an-unsupervised-text-document-e7bb6265f52

Answer (score 0):

You can do biobert to do contextual spelling check,

Link: https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert